Issues with Installing Custom Slack Bot in an Existing Workspace
I’m facing several issues with installing a custom Slack bot in an existing workspace, and I’m not sure how to resolve them. Here’s my situation:

Workspace Context: I am part of a Slack workspace that I did not create. I have been granted the necessary permissions by the workspace admin to install apps.
Bot Development: I have developed a Slack bot and I do not intend to distribute it publicly. This bot is solely for use within our current workspace.
Installation Attempts:


When I try to add the bot using the “Add to Slack” button from the Slack app directory or by using the shareable URL, I encounter issues with the state parameter not being handled correctly.
The error message I get is: Invalid state parameter.
Below is my current code:

# SlackBotApp.py
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response, redirect, session
import json
import logging
from slack_bolt import App, BoltResponse
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler
from slack_bolt.oauth.callback_options import CallbackOptions, SuccessArgs, FailureArgs
from slack_bolt.oauth.oauth_settings import OAuthSettings
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError
from slack_sdk.oauth.installation_store import FileInstallationStore
from slack_sdk.oauth.state_store import FileOAuthStateStore
import uuid
import Constants
from SlashCommand import SlashCommand

class SlackBotApp:
    def __init__(self):
        installation_store_dir = "./data/installations"
        state_store_dir = "./data/states"

        oauth_settings = OAuthSettings(
            client_id=Constants.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=Constants.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
            scopes=["commands", "chat:write", "files:read", "files:write"],
            installation_store=FileInstallationStore(base_dir=installation_store_dir),
            state_store=FileOAuthStateStore(base_dir=state_store_dir, expiration_seconds=600),
            redirect_uri=Constants.SLACK_REDIRECT_URI,
            install_path="/begin_auth",
            redirect_uri_path="/finish_auth",
            callback_options=CallbackOptions(success=self.oauth_success, failure=self.oauth_failure)
        )

        self.slack_app = App(
            signing_secret=Constants.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
            oauth_settings=oauth_settings
        )

        SlashCommand(self.slack_app)
        self.handler = SlackRequestHandler(self.slack_app)

        self.flask_app = Flask(__name__)
        self.flask_app.secret_key = Constants.FLASK_SECRET_KEY or str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.setup_routes()

    def oauth_success(self, args: SuccessArgs) -> BoltResponse:
        return args.default.success(args)

    def oauth_failure(self, args: FailureArgs) -> BoltResponse:
        return args.default.failure(args)

    def setup_routes(self):
        @self.flask_app.route('/')
        def home():
            return "Hello, this is the Slack Bot home page."

        @self.flask_app.route('/slack/events', methods=['POST'])
        def slack_events():
            return self.handler.handle(request)

        @self.flask_app.route('/slack/oauth_redirect', methods=['GET'])
        def oauth_redirect():
            code = request.args.get('code')
            state = request.args.get('state')
            if not code or not state or state != session.pop('state', None):
                return "Invalid state parameter", 400
            return self.handler.handle(request)

        @self.flask_app.route('/slack', methods=['POST'])
        def slack_challenge():
            payload = request.get_data()
            data = json.loads(payload)
            return Response(data["challenge"], mimetype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

        @self.flask_app.route('/slack/install', methods=['GET'])
        def install():
            state = str(uuid.uuid4())
            session['state'] = state
            oauth_url = f"https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={Constants.SLACK_CLIENT_ID}&scope=commands,chat:write,files:read,files:write&state={state}&redirect_uri={Constants.SLACK_REDIRECT_URI}"
            return redirect(oauth_url)

        @self.flask_app.route('/begin_auth', methods=['GET'])
        def begin_auth():
            state = str(uuid.uuid4())
            session['state'] = state
            client_id = Constants.SLACK_CLIENT_ID
            redirect_uri = Constants.SLACK_REDIRECT_URI
            oauth_url = f"https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope=commands,chat:write,files:read,files:write&client_id={client_id}&state={state}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}"
            return redirect(oauth_url)

        @self.flask_app.route('/finish_auth', methods=['GET'])
        def finish_auth():
            code = request.args.get('code')
            state = request.args.get('state')
            if not code or not state or state != session.pop('state', None):
                return "Invalid state parameter", 400

            client_id = Constants.SLACK_CLIENT_ID
            client_secret = Constants.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET
            client = WebClient()
            try:
                response = client.oauth_v2_access(
                    client_id=client_id,
                    client_secret=client_secret,
                    code=code,
                    redirect_uri=Constants.SLACK_REDIRECT_URI
                )
                Constants.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = response['access_token']
                return "Auth complete!"
            except SlackApiError as e:
                return f"Error: {e.response['error']}", 400

        @self.flask_app.route('/slack/command', methods=['POST'])
        def command():
            return self.handler.handle(request)

    def run(self):
        self.flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SlackBotApp()
    app.run()


State Parameter Issues:


When I try to install the app via the shareable URL, I get the error: Invalid state parameter.
It seems like the state parameter is not being handled correctly. Does this happen because I am trying to install it myself instead of having the admin do it?


OAuth Handling:


Am I handling the OAuth redirection and state parameter correctly in my code?


Collaborator Access:


If I add the workspace admin as a collaborator on my app, and they install it directly, will this resolve the issue?


Current Behavior:


When attempting to forcibly add the app and try slash commands, the server logs show:

"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
Although the app should be installed into this workspace, the AuthorizeResult (returned value from authorize) for it was not found.


Install Page Behavior:


When I go to my-domain.com/slack/install, it shows the permission request screen, and upon granting permissions, it results in a Not Found error. How is this different from using the shareable URL?

How can I properly install my Slack bot in our workspace, ensuring the state parameter is correctly handled and the bot functions as intended?
